# Get a setting value, from file located in non-standard dir

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have Sublime's directory structure like this:

```
Packages
   |-- Foo
   |    |-- Markdown.sublime-settings
   |
   |-- Bar
   |    |-- plugin.py
   |
   |-- User
        |-- Markdown.sublime-settings
```

Then, I'm trying to get a `wrap_width` value, stored in `Foo/Markdown.sublime-setting`. For some reason, it seems that `load_setting` method doesn't work, although `save_settings` works fine.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MarkdownSettings(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_activated(self, view):

        path = view.file_name()
        if path:

            e = view.file_name().split('.')[1]
            if e == ("md" or "mmd"):

                # Simple test. It works
                x = sublime.load_settings("Markdown.sublime-settings")
                wrap_width = x.get("wrap_width")
                print(wrap_width) # Prints 50

                # If I change directory to "../Foo", `load_setting` method would not work
                x = sublime.load_settings("../Foo/Markdown.sublime-settings")
                wrap_width = x.get("wrap_width")
                print(wrap_width) # Prints None

                # The code below is added just for demonstration purposes,
                # to show that `save_setting` method works fine.
                x = sublime.load_settings("../Foo/Markdown.sublime-settings")
                x.set("wrap_width", 20)
                sublime.save_settings("../Foo/Markdown.sublime-settings") # File updated
```

How I could get `wrap_width` value stored in `Foo/Markdown.sublime-settings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a path with `load_settings` is not supported.

From http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime:

> Loads the named settings. The name should include a file name and extension, but not a path. The packages will be searched for files matching the `base_name`, and the results will be collated into the settings object. Subsequent calls to `load_settings()` with the `base_name` will return the same object, and not load the settings from disk again.

If you really need to do this, you should use `sublime.decode_value(sublime.load_resource('Packages/Foo/Markdown.sublime-settings'))` instead.